# AWS S3 Multi-Part Unable to resume

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am implementing AWS S3 multipart using python boto3.

I am unable to resume the pending uploads.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='foobarkey', aws_secret_access_key='foobar', region_name='ap-south-1')

key = 'my_long_key'
upload_id = 'upload_id'  # generated using create_multipart_upload method.

# fetching pending upload parts
response = s3_client.list_parts(Bucket='foobarbucker', Key=key, UploadId=upload_id)
print(response['Parts'])
```

How to get the pending parts to resume.

> print(response['Parts']) KeyError: 'Parts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after create_multipart_upload, you have to start upload using:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html

Comment: HPKG I am using **generate_presigned_url**

Comment: can u check this gist? https://gist.github.com/holyjak/b5613c50f37865f0e3953b93c39bd61a

Comment: i am using uppy js package. which need resigned url

Comment: presigned_url will be required once upload is complete afaik

Comment: now facing this **botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (EntityTooSmall) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size
**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233222/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-hpkg).